# JSON.Net getting a dynamic object

Tags: c#, json

I don't think the title of this post explains what the problem is, but I didn't know how to word it.
Basically I have this response from an API of which I have no control over:

```
        "variations":{  
            "1033308042319364133":{  
                "id":"1033308042319364133",
                "order":null,
                "created_at":"2015-07-20 13:45:45",
                "updated_at":"2015-07-20 13:47:11",
                "title":"Male",
                "mod_price":"+0.00",
                "modifier":1033306667720114205,
                "product":0,
                "difference":"+£0.00"
            },
            "1033308953984892967":{  
                "id":"1033308953984892967",
                "order":null,
                "created_at":"2015-07-20 13:47:34",
                "updated_at":"2015-07-20 13:47:34",
                "title":"Female",
                "mod_price":"+0.00",
                "modifier":1033306667720114205,
                "product":0,
                "difference":"+£0.00"
            },
            "1033309404260204585":{  
                "id":"1033309404260204585",
                "order":null,
                "created_at":"2015-07-20 13:48:27",
                "updated_at":"2015-07-20 13:48:27",
                "title":"Male (Junior)",
                "mod_price":"+0.00",
                "modifier":1033306667720114205,
                "product":0,
                "difference":"+£0.00"
            },
            "1033309540147265579":{  
                "id":"1033309540147265579",
                "order":null,
                "created_at":"2015-07-20 13:48:44",
                "updated_at":"2015-07-20 13:48:44",
                "title":"Female (Junior)",
                "mod_price":"+0.00",
                "modifier":1033306667720114205,
                "product":0,
                "difference":"+£0.00"
            }
        }
```

in my c# code I loop through variations like this:

```
// Get our child variants
var variations = model["variations"];
var IsNull = IsJTokenNull(variations);
var variants = !IsNull ? new List<VariationResponseModel>() : null;

// If we have some variations
if (!IsNull)
{

    // Loop through our variations
    foreach (var variant in variations)
    {

        // Add our variant to our list
        variants.Add(CreateVariants(variant.First));
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am using **variant.First** to select the object within the property. My question is, is this the best way to do this? It seems like an awful hack.

Comment: Can you create a .NET object that matches the object you have serialised and then just deserialise the json into an object of that type?

Comment: It looks like what you ought to do is deserialize to a  `Dictionary<string,VariationResponseModel>`, then you should be able to just loop through the keys (and you can transform it into a simple list if you don't need the keys).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a .net `Dictionary` more than a list. If `VariationResponseModel` has the correct properties, you could just do:

```
var variants = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Variant>>(variations);
```

or using the `JObject` class

```
var variants = JObject.Parse(variations).ToObject<Dictionary<string, Variant>>();
```

Both approaches are equivalent, and assume that you got your input as a JSON string. If your input is already a `JObject`, you can just use:

```
var variants = variations.ToObject<Dictionary<string, Variant>>()
```

If you need the variants in a list/enumerable afterwards, just use `variants.Values`

(JsonConvert / JObject is from the Json.net deserializer)

Comment: Using `ToObject()` would achieve the same result if it's already a `JObject`.

Comment: VariationResponseModel only has 2 properties (Id and Title), but the JSON object has a lot more than that.

Comment: Well, one obvious way would be to create a class for all the other properties, or expand the `VariationResponseModel` class